# rails rake creates no models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, models, migrate

I am deploying a heroku app.
I'm running ubuntu 14.04LTS
After git cloning, I copied the migrate files from my previous project and ran:

```
bin/rake db:create db:migrate
```

Everything seemed to be going well until I checked the models folder.
why does rake not create models? How do I fix this?

Comment: EDIT: corrected db:migrate => db:migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo here: it is `db:migrate` (instead of `bd:migrate`). Also, rake does not create models.

To create models along with migrations, use `rails generate model MyModel`.

On the other hand, if all your tables are created using migrations, then just create the model files manually in the app/models folder.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Thank you